# Using external and internal memory for heap

Tags: memory, memory-management, arm, stm32

I have hooked up external SRAM memory in my project. What I want to do is to use malloc() to store data in external OR internal memory in runtime. How can I decide during code execution in which memory store heap data with malloc? I know I have to edit linker script but after that it will store ALL heap data in external memory.
Is there any linker command that can say to allocate next malloc() in external or internal memory? For stack data we can use ****attribute**((section("name"))) variable attribute** but is there anything for heap?

Thank you!

Comment: *For stack data we can use attribute((section("name")))* - this is not true. You can use it for static variables only. Stack variables are going to stack. If you want specific `malloc` behavior, you will have to implement the allocator accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`malloc` from your C library can generally only use memory from one location.  If you use newlib then it finds this memory using `_sbrk`.  The [default implementation of `_sbrk`](https://github.com/bminor/newlib/blob/master/libgloss/arm/syscalls.c) depends on the definition of the symbol `end` or `_end` by the linker script, but you can also implement your own.

You will have to pick one location for `malloc` to access, and use your own custom function to allocate memory from somewhere else.

Many libraries and RTOS implementations do this.  See for example [`mem_malloc` in LwIP](https://git.savannah.nongnu.org/cgit/lwip.git/tree/src/core/mem.c?h=STABLE-2_1_2_RELEASE) or [`rt_alloc_mem` in Keil RTX](https://github.com/ARM-software/CMSIS_5/blob/develop/CMSIS/RTOS/RTX/SRC/rt_Memory.c)

There are many schemes you can use to decide which memory to use, for example having pools of fixed size blocks for a particular purpose.  I tend to use the fastest internal SRAM for `malloc` because it will become quite fragmented.  I then make sure to only use `malloc` for small things and then custom functions for larger allocations.